# Doctrine 2.1 - DAYOFWEEK function alternative?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

in D2.1, querybuilder, how do i use the day of week mysql function, i dont think its available in

```
doctrine but isnt there  a way i could otherwise?

$qb->select('p')
   ->where('YEAR(p.postDate) = :year')
   ->andWhere('MONTH(p.postDate) = :month')
   ->andWhere('DAYOFWEEK(p.postDate) = :dayOfWeek');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a doctrine extension to do the job:

Xyz\SomeBundle\DoctrineExtension\DayOfWeek.php

```
class DayOfWeek extends FunctionNode
{
    public $date;

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return "DAYOFWEEK(" . $sqlWalker->walkArithmeticPrimary($this->date) . ")";
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->date = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();

        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

app/config/config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                dql:
                    datetime_functions:
                        dayofweek: Xyz\SomeBundle\DoctrineExtension\DayOfWeek
```

More detail check here: [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use all of the SQL functions with the query builder. Some of them are defined (`AVG`, `SUM`, etc), but most aren't (including `DAY`/`WEEK`/`MONTH`).

You can still write native SQL:

```php
// creating doctrines result set mapping obj.
$rsm = new Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();

// mapping results to the message entity
$rsm->addEntityResult('AppBundle\Entity\Post', 'p');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('p', 'postDate', 'postDate');

$sql = "SELECT id, postDate
        FROM your_table
        WHERE YEAR(postDate) = ? 
              AND [...]";

$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $your_year_here);
$query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 2016, there is the [`DayOfWeek`](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/src/Query/Mysql/DayOfWeek.php) extension in [`DoctrineExtentions`](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) repository.